# PHP Warning: PHP Startup: Failed to load , The system cannot find the file specified. PHP 7.4 Windows

Tags: windows, apache2.4, php-7.4

Before marking this as a duplicate, hear me out :)

I have some years experience working with PHP on windows, and have even created a portable (for Windows) distribution of an AMP stack: https://thejaka.com/tzwamp/ which I named "WAMP Zero" or TZWAMP. I've used this WAMP distro extensively, and people I know are using it as well. The last (previous) distribution works fine, but when I tried to update the distro to the latest builds of the applications/components from the vendor/distributor sites, I hit a snag. The PHP extensions aren't loading anymore on the new distro. It seems one or more dependencies are not locatable but I don't know what or where from. I tried viewing php_mbstring.dll in a dependency viewer, but couldn't figure out what was the matter. There were a few missing dependencies, but most seemed to be from CRT and I've installed the latest. I'm guessing the missing dependencies can be resolved from PATH environment variable. The following are not loading:

> php_mbstring.dll php_mysqli.dll php_openssl.dll php_pdo_mysql.dll
>   php_mbstring.dll php_mysqli.dll php_openssl.dll php_pdo_mysql.dll

The error messages are like: PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Failed to load ......\php\ext\php_mbstring.dll, The system cannot find the file specified.

Before you start complaining about the relative path, note that on 7.3 it worked fine.

The path to the ext dir is specified relatively, but the path seems to be correct. The same path worked fine in the previous distro of TZWAMP, and when I change the path, the error messages also change leading me to believe the path is correct. Note also that I tried adding php path to PATH environment variable as well.

The successfully working PHP version is 7.3.10.
The problematic PHP version is 7.4.2.
Apache version is 2.4.41

Is anyone aware of any relevant change from 7.3.* to 7.4.*, or else can anyone help me debug the issue and resolve it?

EDIT: I've checked and an absolute path seems to work. However, in order to make this portable, a relative path is required. Relative paths worked with 7.3 and I believe prior major versions. Any ideas?

Comment: Success! I have uploaded the new version of TZWAMP. It should be working now...

Comment: I encountered this same error message (Failed to load ... the system cannot find the file specified) upgrading from 7.2.5 to 7.4.11.   Interestingly, the problem only appeared on two of my selected extensions, php_pgsql and php_pdo_pgsql.   The extension_dir from the prior PHP version was correct, but I also tried referencing the full path name in the extension= statement for those two modules, but that didn't work.  What finally resolved the problem for me was adding ".dll" to the module name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved this for now to my requirements by using an Environment Variable substitution.

`extension_dir = "${P}\php\ext"`

However, a relative path solution would also be welcome.